# Determination of the version of any jar

Tags: java

How can we know about the version of any jar ?

Suppose we have db2jcc4.jar installed in our system. How can we know that the jar is of 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: byte-code is byte-code is byte-code. There is no 32-bit byte-code and 64-bit byte-code.

Comment: If you want to know the version, decompress the jar and look at the manifest file. you can also use a decompiler to look at the code

Comment: your question has simple answer, Java is platform independent, so any jar built by java compiler does not have 32 bit or 64 bit dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Java code is platform-independent, therefore there isn't a notion of a "32 bit" or "64 bit" Jar.

Some applications bundle in platform-dependent components, but you'd need to look at their documentation to determine this sort of information; there's no Java standard. You *might* have luck [inspecting the contents of the Jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) (it's a .zip file with a different extension) however that's not guaranteed to tell you anything useful.